# Mule SFTP : How to create directories on remote location

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-studio

i am trying to send a file over SFTP using mule . We have to specify a fixed path for that , like /home/ftp/ and then file name in outputpattern . but i want to create directories on the fly on remote location . everytime a file is sent , it should be sent in a new directory .

like abc.txt : /home/ftp/abc/abc.txt

pqr.txt : /home/ftp/pqqw/pqr.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this by overriding`FtpMessageDispatcher` in MULE . [Here is the blog post about it](http://www.javaroots.com/2014/09/mule-ftp-create-directory-if-not-exist.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need a custom java component for this folder creation.

http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpClient.html#createSftpDirIfNotExists(org.mule.api.endpoint.ImmutableEndpoint,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: okay , that is what i was thinking about . Is it possible to change existing sftp connector implementation ? so that my flow code would be least modified ?